# SendAndSaveCopy does not send

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I've followed an example from MS (Get started with EWS Managed API).

It works fine to send a message with EmailMessage.Send, but with EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy it just saves a copy of the e-mail in sent folder with the drafts icon. No exception is throwed.

Any ideas anyone?

```
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("nicholas", "XXXXXXX", "mydomain");

            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            string exchangeUrl = "https://XXXXXXXX.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
            service.Url = new Uri(exchangeUrl); 

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            email.ToRecipients.Add("xx@xxxxxx.se");
            email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");

            email.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);


           // email.Send();  // SEND WORKS
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using ? Are the credentials your using that of the owner of the Mailbox ?

Comment: It's Exchange 2013. Yes, the credentials is correct. Here's the output from Trace:

      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="847" MinorBuildNumber="31" Version="V2_8"

Comment: Never see that before your a bit behind on you rollup (eg you only SP1 RU4 and latest is RU7). The Outlook Mac client uses EWS and the same operation and I've never seen that error reported. You might want to check the EWSLog on the CAS server in \Logging\ews this may give you some more information. While the credentials maybe correct are they the credentials of the owner of that Mailbox ? It sounds like you have SendAs rights but not FullAccess to the Mailbox or there is restriction on the Mailbox itself eg over-quota etc can you send okay from OWA?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to check the logs. My credentials should be correct and everything works as excepted with "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx".

Comment: RELATED, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53421766/495455

Answer (score 0):

> no need email.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);
>   use email.SendAndSaveCopy(); 
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634557(v=exchg.80).aspx