# How to remove "on behalf of " while sending mail from C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, automation

This is shared Mailbox that is given access to my email for sending and receiving mails. However when I send the mails via outlook from shared mail box I am not getting the "on behalf of" message whereas when I send it from code I am getting as MyEmail.com on behalf of sharedEmail.com.

```
var app = new Application();
                MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;               
                var attachments = mailItem.Attachments;
                mailItem.Subject = item.Capability + " - " + appSettings["Subject"].ToString();
                mailItem.HTMLBody = CreateBody(appSettings);
                mailItem.CC= appSettings["CCEmails"].ToString();  
                mailItem.Recipients.Add(appSettings["FromAddress"]);
                mailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                var adressEntry = mailItem.Recipients[mailItem.Recipients.Count].AddressEntry;
                mailItem.Recipients.Remove(mailItem.Recipients.Count);                                          
                mailItem.Sender = adressEntry;
                mailItem.To = item.EmailId;    
                mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
                mailItem.Send();
                ReleaseObj(app);
```

Following Things I have already Tried.

1.Using SendUsingAccount -This did not work since the mail is configured as shared mailbox and not as shared account so this mailbox is not listing under the accounts.

2.Using SentOnBehalfOfName-This also is not working , I followed one of  the stack overflow user workaround approach to set the sender name.

3.Many of the answers are suggesting to enable "Send As" or "Behalf of" Permissions from the admin but if permissions is the issue why I am  getting the message "on behalf of " only through code and not via outlook client.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
mailItem.Sender = adressEntry;
```

But seem to be missing the From Address, I haven't tried but adding these lines may override the "on behalf of":

```
EmailAddress fromSender = new EmailAddress();
fromSender.Address = _sharedOutlookMailAccount;
message.From = fromSender;
```

Ref: [How to send email via a Shared MailBox using Exchange Web Services (EWS) API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53421766/495455)

Comment: Thanks for the answering this. Will try it and update the group if it works